# Why does 8thWall restrict image aspect resolution for image tracking

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, 8thwall-web

I'm into computer vision and I came across 8thWall web and their image detection feature. https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#image-targets

Ever since I read the spec I can't stop wondering why they restrict the image aspect to 3:4. As I couldn't find anything on the web I thought I'd ask the community.

Thanks so much for clues.